# Google maps API v3 marker issues

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to code a map where you can search for an address, it shows a list with auto-completed items and when you click it takes the marker to the address. If you want to, you can simply drag the marker and don't use the address search. 
I was using v2 and was successful with it - I could get the lat and lng values and insert them into hidden inputs, so later I could insert them into a DB.
With V3, the best thing I could do was to show a map and make the search work, but I can insert the lat and lng to the hidden input and I can't make the ONLY marker change place. 
 If I create a marker to start with the document, when you search and click it'll create another mark.

Here's my code:

```
function initialize() {

    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-1.456688, -48.477586);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };




  var markers = [];
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      draggable: true,
      title: 'Hello World!'
  });


  // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(
      document.getElementById('pac-input'));


  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(
    /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(input));

  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects an item from the
  // pick list. Retrieve the matching places for that item.
  google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }
    for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    }

    // For each place, get the icon, place name, and location.
    markers = [];
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {
        var image = {
          url: place.icon,
          size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
          origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
          anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
          scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
        };




      // Create a marker for each place.
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location,
        draggable: true
      });

      markers.push(marker);

      bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
    }

    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });

  // Bias the SearchBox results towards places that are within the bounds of the
  // current map's viewport.
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    searchBox.setBounds(bounds);
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I'm sorry for asking that much, but I really spent all my day on the API documentatation and couldn't get it any better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the SearchBox is not suitable when you search for an address, you better use an Places-Autocomplete.

To change the position of the ONLY marker you only have to set the position-property of the marker.

```js
function initialize() {

  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-1.456688, -48.477586);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };


  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    draggable: true,
    title: 'Hello World!'
  });

  //set the value of the hidden inputs when the position changes
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'position_changed', function() {
    document.getElementById('latitude').value = this.getPosition().lat();
    document.getElementById('longitude').value = this.getPosition().lng();
  });

  // Create an Autocomplete and link it to the UI element.
  var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */ (
    document.getElementById('pac-input'));
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(input);

  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */
    (input), {
      types: ['geocode']
    });

  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects an item from the
  // pick list. Retrieve the matching places for that item.
  google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'place_changed', function() {
    var place = this.getPlace();
    //when place has been found
    if (place.geometry) {
      marker.setOptions({
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location
      });
      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        marker.getMap().fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        marker.getMap().setCenter(place.geometry.location);
      }
    }
    //otherwise
    else {
      marker.setOptions({
        title: null
      });
      alert('place not found');
    }
  });

  // Bias the SearchBox results towards places that are within the bounds of the
  // current map's viewport.
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    searchBox.setBounds(bounds);
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
```

```html
<script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=places"></script>
<input id="pac-input"/>
<input type="hidden" id="latitude"/>
<input type="hidden" id="longitude"/>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Hi there, 
Thanks for the answer. I think I didn't express myself right - sorry, english is not my main language.
I need the search box to search for example a avenue. That's not the problem - the searchbox is working fine. The problem is it would create a new marker. I didn't quite understood the position-property of the marker. Also, would       var latt = location.lat(); and 
var lngg = location.lng(); for example work to separate the lat and lng, as they are in separate columns in the DB?
Thanks for the attention!

Comment: The SearchBox is intended to search for terms(let's say "Starbucks" or "bus station") and it may return multiple results(when you have a single marker, which of the results you would choose?). The position-property is the LatLng(location) where the marker will be placed.  Related to `lat()` & `lng()`: correct, these methods return the separate values

Comment: Man, you have no idea of how much you just helped me... I spent all day looking through the API's documentation and you solved my issue with one response. Sorry to bother you again, but is there anyway to get the address text (ex.: 5593 Some Street) and insert it into a hidden input, so then I can get it with a $_POST? Or getting the pac-value $_POST is enough? Thank you very much!!!!

Comment: Basically the pac-input  is a input, you may still use it as a form-element and send it with the form(just give it a `name`). However, `place.formatted_address` would give you the address returned by the API

Comment: Hello there, 
Sorry to bother you again. I'm able to get the value with     <code>   document.getElementById('enderecoo').value = place.formatted_address; </code> but that only Works when the user types the address. Is there anyway to capture the address if the user is changing the marker's place? @Dr.Molle

Comment: To find an address based on a LatLng(e.g. marker-position) use [geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding)